# iPhone doesn't show image generated by aspx website

Tags: html, iphone, image, web

i want to develop an iPhone optimized website, which includes an generated image. To generate the image i call an external website (aspx). Example:

`https://url/filedownload.aspx?documentid=1234&mimetype=image/jpeg`

This is no problem on any standard browser on the pc, the images shows up after 2 seconds. But on the iphone there is only the blue question mark showing.

The resultion is ~ 170 * 100 72dpi.

Comment: Have you tried edit HTTP Response header defining parameter mime type as image/jpeg?

Comment: Do you have an example of the image (ie, a working link) otherwise there isn't that much of a way to help. It doesn't matter what the link is, if the result is a valid image tagged as an image, it shouldn't cause a problem

Comment: I have no working link for public use, sorry. 
Response Header was this: X-Powered-By ASP.NET X-AspNet-Version 2.0.50727 Content-Transfer-Encoding binary Content-Length 3318 Content-Disposition attachment; filename=document_20110214_015144.png Cache-Control private Content-Type image/png

Comment: Has someone a hint or an idea? One suggestion was that the time it takes to generate the image is the problem. But even after i refresh the page on the iphone the image is still not shown.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a server-side issue, as suggested - a working link or a sample of the source is needed to help resolve. In the meantime, some other things to check; does the image type created match that of the content type specified?

I would then try adding the exact same image (as a static physical file) to the website, load this in an iPhone (to prove there is nothing fundamentally wrong with the image file data) and then compare response headers from your dynamic image code to ensure they are the same - do you require attachment-filename for example?